# Do I have any hope with this PIDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$\frac{\omega(1-\omega)}{N_1} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\omega(1-\omega)}{N_2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2} + \cdots
+ \frac{\omega(1-\omega)}{N_k} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_k^2} + \lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1-y, x_2-y,...x_k-y)g(y)dy-\lambda f = -1$
where,

$\omega$ is convex combination of $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k$, and $N_1, N_2, ...N_k$ are just some constants.

I'm fine with anything, method of characteristics, numerical solution, etc.

I'm interested in the solution over the unit hypercube, and the boundary conditions are:
$f= 0$ when all $x_is \geq 1$ and $x_is \leq 0$, and no-flux boundary conditions otherwise.

Comment: I might be missing something but why don't you simplify the $\omega$ in each fraction?

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry, that was just a typo on my part. There's no $\omega$ in the denominator to begin with.